# Dynamic and Keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

I have two standard cubes (A and B). I have a specific animation plan. *Cube A* has a linear movement along the *X* axis. The animation starts at frame #1, the animation ends at frame #30. *Cube B* has a linear movement along the *X* axis. The animation starts at frame #40, the animation ends at frame #70. The linear movement of the cubes is carried out by keyframe animation. In frame #31, the **Rigid Body World** physics simulation begins. The physics simulation of *Cube B* should start at frame #71.

[image]

These two cubes have **Rigid Body** modifiers with standard settings. *Cube A* animates perfectly. To delay the physics simulation of *Cube B* (until frame #71), I use the *Dynamic* option. Disabling *Dynamic* results in blocking the linear motion of *Cube B*.

[image]

How can I exclude the effect of the *Dynamic* option on the linear motion of an object? Can I create multiple instances of **Rigid Body World** in the same scene?

Comment: Blender version 3.0.

Comment: You cannot animate and have rigid body simulation on the same frame. You have to decide: animate it yourself or use physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use rigid body simulations and keyframes animation at the same time.  Either the solid mesh is under full control of physics or it isn't.

What you *can* attempt is keyframing force amounts, depending on what you are trying to do.